# Replace enum with struct inside a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, struct

I know this is an absolute sitter, but somehow I'm not getting the hang of it. Lets say, I have a class `Person` which is as follows  -

```
    public class Person
    {
        //Constructor...
        public Person( string name, Gender gender)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Gender = gender;
        }

        //Member variables...


        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }


        private Gender _Gender;
        public Gender Gender
        {
            get
            {
                return _Gender;
            }
            set
            {
                _Gender = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male = 0,
        Female = 1
    }
```

I do not want the `Gender` to be an `enum` anymore, I want this to be replaced with a `struct` and in the same way as above want to pass it as an argument to the `constructor` of the `Person` class such that when I `create a new object of person class I am able to assign the gender` as well to that person. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: And what fields you want in struct? Having it as enum makes more sense though.

Comment: Agree with you, but what if I want that `Gender` to be a struct? Such that the user passes something like either male or female as an argument while creating an object of that `person` class?

Comment: This is exactly what enum does, isn't it?

Comment: @nima Yes that I understand, but what if I am asked to replace that `enum` with a `struct`?

Comment: Is there any possible way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't get why you have to do this, but if you should you can do something like this:

```
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; private set; }

        public Person(string name, Gender gender)
        {
            Name = name;
            Gender = gender;
        }
    }

    struct Gender
    {
        private int _type;

        public bool IsMale
        {
            get { return _type == 0; }
            set { _type = value ? 0 : 1; }
        }

        public bool IsFemale
        {
            get { return _type == 1; }
            set { _type = value ? 1 : 0; }
        }
    }
```

And to use it:

```
        var p1 = new Person("John", new Gender {IsMale = true});
        var p2 = new Person("Jane", new Gender {IsFemale = true});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *emulate* `enum` by `struct` in this way:

```
// Gender according ISO/IEC 5218 
// See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218
public struct Gender {
  private int m_Value;

  private Gender(int value) {
    m_Value = value;
  }

  private Gender() {
    m_Value = 0;
  }

  public int IsoValue {
    get {
      return m_Value; 
    }
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return m_Value;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if (!(obj is Gender))
      return false;

    return ((Gender) obj).m_Value == m_Value;
  }

  public static Boolean operator ==(Gender left, Gender right) {
    return left.m_Value == right.m_Value;
  }

  public static Boolean operator !=(Gender left, Gender right) {
    return left.m_Value != right.m_Value;
  } 

  public static readonly Gender Male = new Gender(1);
  public static readonly Gender Female = new Gender(2);
  // E.g. "XYZ Corporation"
  public static readonly Gender NotApplicable = new Gender(5);
  // E.g. "Brown" - Mr or Mrs?
  public static readonly Gender Unknown = new Gender(0);
}

...

class Person {
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public Gender Gender { get; set; }

  public Person(string name, Gender gender) {
     Name = name;
     Gender = gender;
  }
}
```